# nginx uwsgi flask rewrite directory as base directory within app

Tags: nginx, python, uwsgi

So I have a flask application running using uWSGI on Nginx. Nginx is set to call my app at the location /app. So in my flask application I have to take into account the /app part when I map the url to a function. Is there a way to rewrite the nginx file or the uwsgi config.xml file to have the application think it is running from the / directory? And are there any side effects?

Just as an example:

the page http://mysite.com/app/ links to my index.py module

my index.py module uses Flask, so the route mapping goes like this:

```
@app.route('/app/')
    def hello_world():
        return 'Hello World!'
```

I am wondering if I can change the config files so I could write:

```
@app.route('/')
   def hello_world():
       return 'Hello World!'
```

Instead?

Answer (score 3):

Mount your app in the subdir in uWSGI with

--mount /app=myfile.py --callable app --manage-script-name

it should work without modifying code or using wsgi middlewares

Comment: Is this a change I can make to my uwsgi xml configuration file?

Answer (score 1):

I made it work by the following nginx config:

```
location ~ ^/app {
    charset utf-8;
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass uwsgicluster;
    uwsgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /app;
    uwsgi_modifier1 30;
}
```

and run uwsgi with --mount and --mange-script-name as @roberto.
eg.

```
uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:3031\ 
            --pythonpath  . \
            --mount /app=./app.py \ 
            --manage-script-name \
            --callable app
```